# How to make LDAP Generalized Time attributes return yyyyMMddHHmmssZ pattern format

Tags: ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Is there a way to set the format used for LDAP Generalized Time attributes in an LDAP server?

For example, my LDAP server will return the last modified timestamp as `20160909205956.988Z` and I want the server to return `20160909205956Z`.

These results happen with an embedded LDAP server using unboundid ldap sdk and creating a ldap server with Apache Directory Studio.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: No, but you can parse it to a Date and then reformat it the way you want.